# After updating to Xcode 4.3, getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS at start up

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5, osx-lion, xcode4.3

I just updated from Snow Leopard to Lion, and from Xcode 4.2 for Snow Leopard to Xcode 4.3 for Lion. Now when I try to build and run an app I'm working on I get a crash before the ever getting to my code. The error message is EXC_BAD_ACCESS. I don't know how to print out my stack trace so I'm including an image of it.[image]

I know that my code was working in Xcode 4.2, because I've checked out clean versions from the source code repository. Also, I've tried to run a few other apps from xcode and they seem to run fine. I have no idea what the problem could be.

I'm using iOS 5.0 as the base SDK.

I have tried cleaning and deleting the app from the simulator.

---

Update:

I still haven't found a solution to this problem, but I did find that I am able to build and run on my iPhone, just not the simulator.

Also, I tried deleting and reinstalling Xcode, with no change.

Comment: Use the Zombies instrument to find out what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I resolved the issue. I went into the Target Build Settings, in the Linker section, and cleared everything out of the Other Linker Flags. One of these must have been causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting NSZombieEnabled to YES in your project settings. If you have trouble from there, post up the code that it is crashing on and maybe we can help further.

Comment: I've never used NSZombies before so I'm not sure how to use them, but I set NSZombieEnabled to YES and ran again with the exact same result. The app is crashing before it enters the code I've written, so I can't post any code. The splash screen image does show, but the crash happens before the code gets to any of my AppDelegate methods.

Comment: I'm not sure then. If its not any of your code causing the crash it may be your installation of XCode. Maybe someone else can chime in.

Answer (score 0):

remove all the linker flag like 
**OTHER LINKING FLAG**.

Check your linker flags. Some libraries you might have been using required a flag like this:

`-weak_library /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib`